# Multi Theft Auto HTML Login

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, mta

I have such a minor problem and I still can not solve it, so I turn around here

```js
function myFunction() {
    var checkbox = $.cookie('checkbox');
    if (checkbox == 'true') 
    {
        var UsernameInput = $.cookie('id');
        var PasswordInput = $.cookie('password');
        $('#id').attr("value", UsernameInput);
        $('#password').attr("value", PasswordInput);
    }
});
}
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
  <div class="head">
    <img src="images/mem2.jpg" alt=""/>

  </div>
<form method="POST" class="form login" action="javascript:loginTrigger()" form id="loginform">
  <li>
    <input type="text" id="UsernameInput" class="text" value="Username" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'USERNAME';}" ><a href="#" class=" icon user"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="password" id="PasswordInput" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}"><a href="#" class=" icon lock"></a>
  </li>
  <div class="p-container" action"myFunction()">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked />
                      <label for="Remember Me"></label>
        <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" >
      <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

What is wrong? I can add
`action="javascript:myFunction()"`

It does not save anything, can it be done in MTA at all in order to retrieve the login data into the site?

Comment: why is this tagged `mta` - i.e *Multi Threaded Apartment of the Component Object Model*

Comment: `javascript:loginTrigger()` ... where is this `loginTrigger` function declared? `div ... action"myFunction()"` ... two things wrong here ... a `div` has no action property, and there's a missing `=`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the code in your question and moved it to a StackSnippet, making it easier for others to debug. Please include all the functions used in your JavaScript, as any errors can be within them. Good Luck!

Comment: @JaromandaX MTA ? Multi Theft Auto - Game by the way

Comment: hover over the mta tag ... then delete it when you see it's irrelevant to your question :p

Answer (score 0):

But sorry @Jaromanda X. Here is `loginTrigger`

```
function loginTrigger() {
var UsernameValue = $( "#UsernameInput" ).val();
var PasswordValue = $( "#PasswordInput" ).val();
mta.triggerEvent("belepesfunkc", UsernameValue, PasswordValue)

}
function registerTrigger() {
var UsernameValue = $( "#UsernameInputR" ).val();
var PasswordValue = $( "#PasswordInputR" ).val();
var PasswordCValue = $( "#PasswordCInputR" ).val();
mta.triggerEvent("belepesfunkcregisztral", UsernameValue, PasswordValue, 
PasswordCValue)

}

function guestTrigger() {

mta.triggerEvent("guest")

}

function gotologinfromregister(){
$("#registerform").hide(1000);
$("#loginform").show(1000);
document.getElementById("UsernameInputR").value = "";
document.getElementById("PasswordInputR").value = "";
document.getElementById("PasswordCInputR").value = "";

}
```

Comment: is that an answer? or should this be part of the question?